# Incorrect Data From CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerInfomation…)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Trying to get some data from CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerInfomation…) but the returned data doesn't seem to be correct (lidpresent should be true but it's false, VideoDimPresent should be false but it's true..)  I'm new to C++ and I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

My code:

```
#include <NTstatus.h>
#define WIN32_NO_STATUS
#include <windows.h>
#include <Powrprof.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")

int main()
{

   SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES spwr;
   NTSTATUS status = ::CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerInformation, NULL, 0, &spwr, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES));

    if(STATUS_SUCCESS == status){

      if(spwr.LidPresent){
        std::cout << "LidPresent TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "LidPresent FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
      if(spwr.VideoDimPresent){
        std::cout << "VideoDimPresent TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "VideoDimPresent FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
      if(spwr.SystemS1){
        std::cout << "SystemS1 TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "SystemS1 FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
      if(spwr.SystemS2){
        std::cout << "SystemS2 TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "SystemS2 FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
      if(spwr.SystemS3){
        std::cout << "SystemS3 TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "SystemS3 FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
      if(spwr.SystemS4){
        std::cout << "SystemS4 TRUE!" << std::endl;
      }else{
        std::cout << "SystemS4 FALSE!" << std::endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "CallNtPowerInformation failed. Status: " << status << std::endl;
   }

   return status;
}
```

Comment: Please do not change the question to render an answer invalid. If you have a follow up question, make it a new question. I believe that this one has been correctly answered. You should accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed `SystemPowerInformation`, so `lpOutputBuffer` is expected to point to `SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION` structure.

You may want to pass `SystemPowerCapabilities` rather than `SystemPowerInformation` if you expect `SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES`.

See [`CallNtPowerInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Changed SystemPowerInformation to SystemPowerCapabilities, but I'm still not getting the right data.  Lidpresent should be "true" but I'm getting "false".